# Chart bars not aligning with x axis values in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, data-visualization

Trying to learn and *implement* [d3.js](https://d3js.org) for the first time.

In the fiddle, we needed to *reduce the width of each bar* from

[`.attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())`](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/499q0un9/) line 46

to

[`.attr('width', '10')`](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/nmjxx6t0/) line 50

When doing so, the horizontal x axis labels are getting **dis-aligned with vertical bars** which is not needed.

Tried to see a few solutions:

- We're unable to see [`tickValues`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36067544/2404470) anywhere in my code.
- Unable to understand where to put [`SVG-Text`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354563/2404470)
- We do not wish to [hide the x axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35407263/2404470)
- Ours is numeric, they're [discussing about date time kind of axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926272/2404470)

*Any suggestions, kind folks?*

Comment: Instead of using magic numbers, why don't you tweak the value at `.rangeBands([0, width], someValue)`? Check This modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lz5y9L8m/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Solved like a boss. Can you also please educate me how did you decided to tweak `rangeBands`?

Comment: Sure: that (optional, btw) value after the array sets the padding (in your case, the padding between the bars). Note: this doesn't work in D3 4.x.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Can you suggest us [`c3.js`](http://c3js.org/) vs [`nvd3`](http://nvd3.org/index.html). Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Regarding c3 and nvd3, I never used any of them. Regarding the answer, do yourself a good research and write an answer, explaining it and also explaining `paddingInner` in the new v4.x. After some time, you can accept your own answer!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Oh man!! You're damn geek. Thanks anyways  :) We're internally thinking of going with one of these, instead of directly using d3.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

`.rangeBands([0, width], someValue)`